# How best to migrate personal queries?

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

First, I just want to say what a fantastic toolset this is...thank you for all your hard work, Martin.  So, my question is:
What would be the best method to migrate the personal queries since the tool only migrates Shared Queries?  Write something using the API, or just provide instructional doc/video on how to export/import from Team Explorer?  Perhaps there's an easier way to export/import that I don't know about.  TIA...

Comment: I see this extension, Wiql Editor, claims to export/import, anyone ever used it:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor

Comment: That's a good extension, but the Export button doesn't work from TFS 2017.3.1.  Have to copy and save the WIQ manually as .wiq extension, then use the import on the Azure DevOps side.  Close enough, and doesn't require all the users to install Team Explorer.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to create a folder for everyone that has personal queries and have them individually all alky copy the ones that they want to keep over into the shared queries folder.

Then you can just run the migration tool.